# Vuex add new array property to an object and push elements to that object inside mutation in a reactive manner

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

According to the [Official docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules), vuex **mutations** has some limitation in reactivity.

When **adding a new property to an object** we have to do,

```
Vue.set(obj, 'newProp', 123)
```

This is fine. But how do we add new **array** property and **push** elements to that without breaking the reactivity?

This is what I have done up to now. This is working fine but the problem is this is not reactive. `Getters` can't recognize the changes happen to the state.

```
set_add_ons(state, payload) {
        try {

            if (!state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].add_ons) {
                state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].add_ons = [];
            }
            state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1].add_ons.push(payload);


        } catch (error) {
            console.log("ERR", error)
        }
    },
```

How do I convert this to a code which is reactive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Vue.set` to create the `add_ons` attribute to make it reactive; It should work for array too:

```
Vue.set(state.tour_plan[state.tour_plan.length - 1], 'add_ons', []);
```

*Demo*:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [{ id: 0 }]
  },
   methods: {
    addArray () {
      if (!this.items[this.items.length-1].add_on)
        this.$set(this.items[this.items.length - 1], 'add_on', [])
      this.items[this.items.length - 1].add_on.push(1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="addArray">
    Add 1 to add_on create if not exists
  </button>
  <div v-for="item in items">add_on content: {{ item.add_on }}</div>
</div>
```